# python как убить процесс на linux

Tags: python, node.js

использую следующий код

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['node', 'index.js'])
while(True):
    time.sleep(10)
 
    if psutil.pid_exists(p.pid) == False:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['node', 'index.js'])
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        p.kill()
```

Как вы можете видеть он запускает node скрипт и если процесс умирает он поднимает его заново.

На windows данный скрипт работает отлично, но на Linux наблюдаются проблемы:
psutil.pid_exists(p.pid) всегда выводит true, он либо не может убить процесс, либо не правильно определяет.

В чем проблема, как написать данный скрипт под linux ?

Comment: А зачем вы используете pid_exists, если статус процесса можно контролировать просто через p.poll или p.wait?

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо

Comment: А по сути вопроса «в чём проблема» — вероятно, в том, что в линуксе процесс исчезает только после того, как родительский процесс прочитает его код завершения, а так как вы его никогда не читали (не использовали poll или wait), процесс оставался в состоянии [зомби](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8) и ждал

Comment: А это не проблема то что я в цикле могу несколько раз убить процесс, не получится ли такое что процессы-зомби переполнят таблицу процессов или после того как я использую poll зомби благополучно умирает?

Comment: Благополучно умирает

Answer (score 0):

Проверять процесс через p.poll()

```
poll = p.poll()
if poll == None:
  # p.subprocess is alive
```